# Можно ли игнорировать namespace без префикса, не удаляя его из исходного xml?

Tags: xml, xslt

есть xml файл:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request 
    xmlns="http://www.ucbreport.ru/2021/UCH"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    schemaVersion="1.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ucbreport.ru/2021/UCH UCH758Report.xsd">
    <person>
        <name>
            <firstName>test</firstName>
            <lastName>test</lastName>
            <midName>test</midName>
        </name>
        <prevName/>
        <birthInfo>
            <birthDate>20.07.2001</birthDate>
            <countryCode>643</countryCode>
            <birthPlace>test</birthPlace>
        </birthInfo>
        <id>
            <countryCode>643</countryCode>
            <idCode>21</idCode>
            <idSeries>1111</idSeries>
            <idNum>111111</idNum>
            <issueDate>23.08.2021</issueDate>
            <issuer>test</issuer>
            <deptCode>111-222</deptCode>
        </id>
        <prevId/>
    </person>
    <consent>
        <givenTo>
            <org>
                <name>
                    <fullName>test</fullName>
                    <shortName>-</shortName>
                </name>
                <regNum>123</regNum>
            </org>
        </givenTo>
        <hashCode>123qwe123</hashCode>
        <date>17.04.2023</date>
        <expireCode>1</expireCode>
        <requestReason>3</requestReason>
        <accountabilityAcknowledged>1</accountabilityAcknowledged>
    </consent>
    <requestInfo>
        <requestReason>3</requestReason>
        <amount>1000,00</amount>
        <currency>RUB</currency>
    </requestInfo>
</request>
```

А так же xslt преобразование

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    
    <xsl:output method="text" 
        indent="no" 
        omit-xml-declaration="yes" 
        encoding="UTF-8"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>firstName=</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="/request/person/name/firstName"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>lastName=</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="/request/person/name/lastName"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>midName=</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="/request/person/name/midName"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>birthDate=</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="/request/person/birthInfo/birthDate"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>idSeries=</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="/request/person/id/idSeries"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>idNum=</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="/request/person/id/idNum"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

При наложении преобразования на xml файл в итоге получается пустой ответ, ошибка в строке xmlns="http://www.ucbreport.ru/2021/UCH" в xml файле, но удалять его нельзя, так как он требуется в других операциях, с помощью преобразования нужно просто вытянуть требуемые данные из файла.

Как это сделать, не трогая пространства имён?

Comment: Что нового? У вас была возможность попробовать предложенное решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Невозможно игнорировать пространство имен по умолчанию. И не надо этого делать.

В XSLT 2.0 для этого было введено предложение 'xpath-default-namespace'.

**Входной XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request xmlns="http://www.ucbreport.ru/2021/UCH" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" schemaVersion="1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ucbreport.ru/2021/UCH UCH758Report.xsd">
    <person>
        <name>
            <firstName>test</firstName>
            <lastName>test</lastName>
            <midName>test</midName>
        </name>
        <prevName/>
        <birthInfo>
            <birthDate>20.07.2001</birthDate>
            <countryCode>643</countryCode>
            <birthPlace>test</birthPlace>
        </birthInfo>
        <id>
            <countryCode>643</countryCode>
            <idCode>21</idCode>
            <idSeries>1111</idSeries>
            <idNum>111111</idNum>
            <issueDate>23.08.2021</issueDate>
            <issuer>test</issuer>
            <deptCode>111-222</deptCode>
        </id>
        <prevId/>
    </person>
    <consent>
        <givenTo>
            <org>
                <name>
                    <fullName>test</fullName>
                    <shortName>-</shortName>
                </name>
                <regNum>123</regNum>
            </org>
        </givenTo>
        <hashCode>123qwe123</hashCode>
        <date>17.04.2023</date>
        <expireCode>1</expireCode>
        <requestReason>3</requestReason>
        <accountabilityAcknowledged>1</accountabilityAcknowledged>
    </consent>
    <requestInfo>
        <requestReason>3</requestReason>
        <amount>1000,00</amount>
        <currency>RUB</currency>
    </requestInfo>
</request>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.ucbreport.ru/2021/UCH">
    
    <xsl:output method="text" 
        indent="no" 
        omit-xml-declaration="yes" 
        encoding="UTF-8"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/request">
        <xsl:text>firstName=</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="person/name/firstName"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>lastName=</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="person/name/lastName"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>midName=</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="person/name/midName"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>birthDate=</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="person/birthInfo/birthDate"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>idSeries=</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="person/id/idSeries"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>idNum=</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="person/id/idNum"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Результат**

```
firstName=test;lastName=test;midName=test;birthDate=20.07.2001;idSeries=1111;idNum=111111;
```

**Другой вариант XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xpath-default-namespace="http://www.ucbreport.ru/2021/UCH">

    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"
                encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="/request">
        <xsl:for-each select="person/*/*">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(local-name(),'=', .,';')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```